# React addEventListener on mount or update?

Tags: reactjs

Simple question, should I add a new listener every time it updates, or only on initial render. I don't understand how the shadow dom works, and if I will need to add it after every render

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you provide some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `ref`, you only need to add a listener once -- anytime after it renders for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

All events are in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html):

Very simple. The React DOM is an abstraction of the Browser DOM, which is also an abstraction of the on page elements. So React DOM is an abstraction of an abstraction.

And all the events we have in React are not native Browsers events. They are called synthetic events. Events system is a wrapper around native Browsers events to support platform independence.

Once you define the React Component using `React.Component` syntax, you are also free to set any event listeners like this:

```
// somewhere inside render
return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </a>
);
```

This code will render using `React.createElement` and will stay inside React DOM.

If you check the component lifecycle you see that `render()` is in both mount and update.

[image]

Hopefully this answers your quest.